# File transfer with winsock (c++)

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I can't transfer the file using the socket. I mean It's possible to transfer the file but it is constantly different-sized. There is a fragment of the code for transfer:

```
FILE *inFile = fopen(this->FullDir, "r+b");
//FILE *outFile = fopen(this->DeskDir, "w+b");
if (inFile != 0)
{
    char* buffer[16384]; //выделяем блок 16Кб
    while (!feof(inFile)) //пока не конец файла
    {
        fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), inFile); //копируем блок
        send(s, (char*)&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);//передаём блок
    }
}
```

And for reception:

```
do
 {
    msg_len = recv(new_client_socket, (char*)&buffer, MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH, 0);
    fwrite(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), output);
  } while (msg_len > 0);
```

The size of the file is 2,50Mb; the size differs from 1MB to 2,2Mb. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Are you sure that you meant to write `sizeof(buffer)`? I mean, it's the number of bytes in the entire buffer, not the size. Also, I doubt the buffer is entirely full.

Comment: BTW: I'm referring to the `fwrite`

Comment: I tried and sizeof(buffer) and MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH (16384), the result is always the same

Comment: What is the value of `msg_len`? You shouldn't attempt to write more than that into `output` during `fwrite`

Comment: msg_len always return 16384

Comment: Okay, but for the last `recv`, `msg_len` will be `0`, yet you will still call `fwrite`. You should rethink the `do-while` loop, and perhaps use a traditional `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 4 fixes needed for your code:

- the sender needs to take the return value of fread and send that many bytes initially
- the receiver needs to write msg_len bytes instead of sizeof(buffer)
- especially if the sending socket is set in non-blocking mode, the send() function may not send all the given data in one call. You need to look at the return value of send() and have a loop that sends() the data and advances the buffer until all of it has been sent
- As a bonus item, you should remove the & and the (char *) cast in the sender from "(char*)&buffer". "buffer" is already the address of the first itgem in the buffer.